# ubuntu installing error ?

Tags: ubuntu

i have bought a new asus laptop with win vista installed , i tried to install 
ubuntu 9.10 64bit
inside windows but when it boot for first time it display an error message :
"dont find root file system"
and when i tried to install it into a single partition (i have 5 partition ) it doesnt figure any partition on the hard disk .
help please 
thanks

Comment: Sys-Specifications please.

Comment: *five* partitions? Why?

Comment: Explain what you did in more detail, please.  The question as written is quite vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion.

On Windows install SUN Virtualbox http://www.virtualbox.org, which manages virtual computers. Each virtual computer has a "hard disk" which is really just a big file in windows, and a "cdrom" which can either be the real cdrom or another big file (compatible with CD image files in ISO format such as the ISO file you get for Ubuntu if you download the CD image file to try to burn your own CD).

Then install your Ubuntu (or other versions of linux you want to try) into a virtual box.

When you do it this way you will not have to worry about how the partitioning of Ubuntu interacts with windows.  The main disadvantage is a moderate speed hit.  However, you will be able to run windows and ubuntu at the same time without rebooting, which some might consider an advantage.